# Fire an event when a div changes by a javascript in a webBrowser1 in a winforms

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

I have a C# winform app that is collecting some data from console-based commands. After the first step of data collecting is done I open a web browser control and direct it to a flash and javascript-based site that tests the download/upload speed to a server.

After the flash app is done cheking the speed, it updates a `<div>` through a javascript call.

I am trying to collect the data the flash app sends to the JavaScript. I want to pass it to a string variable inside my winforms app. Is there a way to snap it up as it is passed to the `<div>`, or is there a way of reading it in to a variable after it is displayed on the site.

The HTML that calls the script is

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="speedtest/functions.js"></script>

<br />

<div id="speed"></div>
```

The data i want in to my variable is this form the script download_speed and upload_speed.

Any suggestions on how i can do this? i have no control to edit the html og the javascript on the site.

Comment: If you can't edit either the HTML or the JavaScript, what approach do you intend to take?

Comment: well i load the page and have the result in plane text on the webbrowser control inside my app, so i was thinking there must be a way to extract the information trough code somehow.

Comment: Well you probably should post more detail about the nature of your application, since most people would definitely not assume you're talking about a page shown in a browser controlled by some other desktop/mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working after the flash start i start a timer that monitors the div and looks for changes

this is a mockup of the code i needed

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        content = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("speed");
        string x = content.OuterHtml;
        if (x != CheckString)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show(x);

        }
    }
```